# Hide a row in a datagrid using Visual Basic

Tags: jquery, vb.net, datagridview

I need to hide the rows that are null and I was wondering if it is better to use a function that automatically does that, or it is better to hide it by using the click function. Also, the only way I got the Delete column I used the  I cannot add the delete under the  So my question is how do I write in Visual Basic a function that hides a null row, or how do I write a buttonHide_Click method to do that or a jquery?

Thank you!

I was able to write this but I don't understand the meaning of --For Each Row As DataGrid In CType --

```
Private Sub dg_DataBindingComplete(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As  System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGridItemEventArgs) Handles dg.ItemDataBound

    For Each Row As DataGrid In CType(ItemTemplate, DataRowView)
        Dim Visible As Boolean = True

        'Do this to inspect all cells in the row
        For i As Integer = 0 To Row.Cells.Count - 1
            If Row.Cells(i).Value Is Nothing Then
                Visible = False
                Exit For
            End If
        Next

        'Or you can check specific columns for their values
        If Row.Cells(0).Value Is Nothing OrElse _
        (IsNumeric(Row.Cells(0).Value) AndAlso CInt(Row.Cells(0).Value) < 0) Then
            Visible = False
        End If

        Row.Visible = Visible
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe you can improve on the SQL querey to not retrieve NULL records?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I don't understand the meaning of --For Each Row As DataGrid In CType --**

```
For Each Row As DataGrid In CType
```

Is a For Each loop that is iterating through all the rows in the DataGrid of type DataRowView. Since a **Row** is compatible with **DataRowView**, the **CType** method tries to convert each/any row of type **ItemTemplate** to **DataRowView** so you can then access that specific Row properties.

If you do not convert each row to DataRowView, then it is difficult to access the individual cells of that row when it’s of type ItemTemplate (you will then need to do some more CTypes). So, your code converts it to DataRowView so it can conveniently access properties like Cells, Visible, Value, etc...